# How does chopping the media file into segments work with MPEG-DASH?

Tags: mpeg-dash

The basic idea behind MPEG-DASH is to chop the media file into segments (e.g. low, medium and best) which can be encoded at different bitrates.

Do I need to do that in advance and offline, or do I need some sort of streaming HTTP server that reads whatever I have in the filesystem and encodes in realtime?